# parsing string with special characters (subprocess.run stdout)

Tags: python, regex, subprocess, gh-api, ansi.sys

I am grabbing output of CLI call (for context GithubAPI)

command:

```
import subprocess
j = subprocess.run("gh api /orgs/{__org__}/teams", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,   text=True)
```

the `j.stdout` object is a type `str` with the API response.

Then I print it `print(j.stdout)` it prints fine:

```
  {
    "name": "Devs",
    "id": {___VALUE HIDDEN____},
    "node_id": "{___VALUE HIDDEN____}",
    "slug": "devs"
    ...
```

However when I try to use it raw `s` the encoding is all wrong.

```
    '\x1b[1;38m[\x1b[m\n  \x1b[1;38m{\x1b[m\n    \x1b[1;34m"name"\x1b[m\x1b[1;38m:\x1b[m \x1b[32m"Devs"\x1b[m\x1b[1;38m,\x1b[m\n    \x1b[1;34m"id"\x1b[m\x1b[1;38m:\x1b[m {___VALUE HIDDEN____}\x1b[1;38m,\x1b[m\n    \x1b[1;34m"node_id"\x1b[m\x1b[1;38m:\x1b[m \x1b[32m"{___VALUE HIDDEN____}"\x1b[m\x1b[1;38m,\x1b[m\n    \x1b[1;34m"slug"\x1b[m\x1b[1;38m:\x1b[m \x1b[32m"devs"\x1b[m\x1b[1;38m,\x1b[m\n  ...
```

I have spent a good portion of today in the rabbit hole of decoding and encoding bytes likes this, began trying to manually clean some of the control characters (e.g. `\x1b`).

How can I get the clean underlying data so I can parse it into a data structure (it's JSON / list of dicts).

It cannot be this hard - I am surely missing something trivial. right?

Comment: `x1b[1;38m` looks a bit like an foreground ANSI color code if that helps

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, there is no reason to prefer `shell=True` here; you want to avoid it whenever you can. See [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing [ANSI.SYS color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that make the output look pretty in the shell.

There are two solutions.  The first is to find [a parameter for the gh api to tell it not to add color codes](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_help_formatting).  That will give you a clean input.  The other solution is to [use regular expressions to strip the codes](https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream) from the data stream.